# Is there any regular expression for finding and extract the string from a text

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a List of paths stored in a text file. I am trying to extract the full path from this text using a regular expression.

**The text file data**

```
/IVTP/DB_db/0171-0_7-296&519_510&586-501&586_296&585_305&519_510&520-0_9_25_31_33_33_32-205-35.jpg 
/IVTP/DB_db/0069-0_2-450&447_581&491-579&491_450&490_452&447_581&448-0_0_9_29_17_24_30-209-15.jpg 
/IVTP/DB_base/0395-4_7-175&502_475&612-456&612_175&590_194&502_475&524-10_0_9_14_26_27_27-206-22.jpg 
/IVTP/DB_base/0234-7_21-271&499_461&602-461&602_291&580_271&499_441&521-0_0_1_32_31_31_18-215-37.jpg 
/IVTP/DB_cc/0291-0_7-271&483_527&578-517&574_271&578_281&487_527&483-0_0_20_29_33_26_18-212-93.jpg 
/IVTP/DB_cc/0325-1_6-227&475_507&572-499&565_227&572_235&482_507&475-0_0_23_28_33_25_33-212-30.jpg
```

**I read the file as Text**

```
imgs_abs_path = [line.strip() for line in open('/home/img_data.txt', 'r') if line.strip() != '']
#converting the list to string 
imgs_paths_to_str = ",".join(str(x) for x in imgs_data_abs_path)
# lis the images from the dataset
imgs_data = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.jpg')]
```

**My problem**

After reading each image, I want to check if the name exists in the text file using a regular expression. If it does, then I want to extract the absolute path from the text file.

> I used this regular expression but it always return empty
> "(/IVTP/*"+img+")"

**My code**

```
new_list = []
for img in imgs_data:
   if search(img, imgs_paths_to_str):
       regex = "(/IVTP/*"+img+")"
       new_list.append(re.findall(regex, imgs_paths_to_str))

print(print(new_list))
[]
```

Comment: `with open('/home/img_data.txt', 'r') as f: print(re.findall(r'^/IVTP/.*\.jpg$', f.read(), re.M))`? If you just want to extract all lines that start with `/IVTP/` and end with `.jpg`, this should suffice.

Comment: Wiktor gave to you a good solution, however if you want to get the name or path, you can using groups this expression might work for you `(\/IVTP\/(.*?\/)(.*)$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  print(re.findall(r'^/IVTP/.*\.jpg$' return all matched But i want all the matched with the file name  r'^/VTP/.' +img.split('.')[0]+ '*\.jpg$' gives me []

Comment: image name = "0207-0_3-251&476_462&558-457&558_251&557_256&476_462&477-0_0_28_16_31_32_32-132-3.jpg"

Comment: @JhoubertRincon it return []

Comment: Try printing what are you getting in the regex execution line, maybe you can notice what's wrong

Comment: `/*` searches for zero or more slashes.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/7u4uy3

Comment: as ive 655k files it take good time till it end but i test for afew list its perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding the paths from the text file into `imgs_paths_to_str` *list*, not a string, and then just check agains the files found in the current directory, and only keep those that start with your required prefix and end with the file name found in the directory:

```py
imgs_paths_to_str = []

with open('/home/img_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            imgs_paths_to_str.append(line)

imgs_data = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.jpg')]

new_list = []
for img in imgs_data:
    for ipts in imgs_paths_to_str:
        if ipts.startswith('/IVTP/') and ipts.endswith(img):
            print(ipts) # new_list.append(ipts)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7u4uy3).